# Using Keycloak with Postgres socket

Tags: sockets, keycloak

I am trying to containerize my keycloak application and I am trying to make it so that the keycloak instance connects to the psotgres socket instead of its hostname. But the keycloak instance crashes almost instantly.
Is it not possible to make keycloak connect to postgres socket? or am I using the wrong connection params?
POSTGRES_ENV:

```
POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

KEYCLOAK_ENV:

```
DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
DB_ADDR=/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
DB_DATABASE=keycloak
DB_USER=postgres
DB_SCHEMA=public
DB_PASSWORD=postgres # change this in prod
```

I have tried changing my docker mount from bind into volumes. Tried changing the file permissions, and even tried different keycloak versions. It is always the same class of error.

Comment: `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` is a Unix domain socket. You can only connect to a Unix domain socket when Keycloak and PostgreSQL are running on the same host. If that is not the case, you need provide the database hostname and port. This will connect to the database using TCP/IP sockets.

Comment: @rveerd I tried replicating the same config in a VM, installing postgres and keycloak in the same host and tried it that way. It still did not connect.

Comment: You should check the Keycloak and PostgreSQL logs for warnings and errors.